# Gcc Inline ASM input variable

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I've this code:

```
void  geninterrupt (int x) {
    __asm__(
    "movb x, %al \n"
        "movb %al, genint+1 \n"
        "jmp genint \n"
    "genint: \n"
        "int $0 \n"
    );
}
```

How can I make `movb` use the argument of `geninterrupt()`?

Comment: See http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the constraints fields correctly:

```
void  geninterrupt (int x) {
  __asm__("  movb %[x], %%al \n"
          "  movb %%al, genint+1 \n"
          "  jmp genint \n"
          "genint: \n"
          "  int $0 \n"
         : /* no outputs */
         : [x] "m" (x) /* use x as input */
         : "al" /* clobbers %al */
         );
}
```

[Here's a good how-to about GCC inline assembly](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) and a [link to the relevant GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Edit: since your GCC seems to not be able to handle the labeled operands

Comment: Thanks Carl (for both this and the pack(pop) question, I'm having a lot of difficulties tonight..), but I got this error with your code: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter
   __asm__("  movb %[x], %al \n"

Comment: Whoops - missed some `%` signs.  Fixed now.  I also had to change to an `m` constraint.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! Thank you very much mate!! Also thank you very much for both the useful links !! :)